# help users to populate fields

Tags: users, entities, navigation

I am making a drupal 7 site and one of the content type has multiple fields, I was wondering if there was a way to assist my users in editing the pages. I looked at the edit function but could not get the fields links to display.

Any alternative suggestions would be great, even something were I can add a graphic to the edit page showing the layout of the page.

Thanks,

Comment: Would using the "description" field on the various fields' settings work?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) is what you are looking for

Here a very useful webinar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vy6fnsawNjE where you will understand what is Panelizer and all its features, also there is quite documentation in the web about this module.

If i missunderstood the question let me know, I will update it if that is the case